# Edit Target on *.lnk with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, target, lnk

I have a shortcut at C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Shortcut.lnk. The current target is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" https://localhost:443/WebApp
```

My goal is to change the target to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" https://FullyQualifiedDomainName/WebApp
```

My Google searches are coming up almost empty when I try to find a way to do this via PowerShell. Has anyone figured out a way to make this happen?  I followed the steps here:

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-change-shortcut-lnk-targets-in-bulk-using-script/

and came up with:

```
$oldPrefix = "localhost:443"
$newPrefix = "FullyQualifiedDomainName"
$searchPath = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"

$shell = new-object -com wscript.shell
write-host "Updating shortcut target" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor black

dir $searchPath -filter *.lnk -recurse | foreach {
$lnk = $shell.createShortcut( $_.fullname )
$oldPath= $lnk.targetPath
$lnkRegex = "^" + [regex]::escape( $oldPrefix )

if ( $oldPath -match $lnkRegex ) {
$newPath = $oldPath -replace $lnkRegex, $newPrefix

write-host "Found: " + $_.fullname -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
write-host " Replace: " + $oldPath
write-host " With: " + $newPath
$lnk.targetPath = $newPath
$lnk.Save()
}
}
```

I then ran:

```
powershell -noexit -executionpolicy bypass -file .\lnk_change.ps1
```

It just sits at:

```
Updating shortcut target
```

And never seems to do anything. Anyone know of a better way to do this that will actually work?

Update:  I found that I can actually view the argument of the target with:

```
$sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$arguments = $sh.CreateShortcut('C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Shortcut.lnk').Arguments
```

But I'm still not quite sure of how I could change it.

Comment: Indeed, the value you're trying to update is in `.Arguments` rather than `.TargetPath`, which you can also assign to, just like you're doing with `.TargetPath`, and as also shown in the linked duplicate. I hope that resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I got it working with this before I noticed your comment:

```
$FQDN = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).HostName

$sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$link = $sh.CreateShortcut('C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Shortcut.lnk')
$link.Arguments = $link.Arguments.Replace('localhost:443',$FQDN)
$link.Save()
``` (and apparently I have no idea how to format a comment)

Comment: . Re formatting in comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - in short: you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks. Unlike in posts, there must be _no whitespace_ after the opening and before the closing delimiter. _Multi_-`\`` delimiters for support of embedded `\`` chars. are supported (e.g. `\`\`"\`n"\`\``). Unlike in posts, ``\`` can alternatively be used to escape `\``, which, due to the no-whitespace requirement, is a must if you want to produce something like `\`enclosed\``. To produce a formatted ``\`` alone, use `\`\`\\`\``